# Compare sums of specific fields in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  | price1 | price2 | price3 | price4 |
1   |   2    |    3   |    3   |   2    |
2   |   3    |    4   |    3   |   3    |
3   |   5    |    6   |    5   |   5    |
4   |   4    |    4   |    5   |   4    |
5   |   3    |    2   |    3   |   2    |   
6   |   2    |    3   |    2   |   2    |
```

I need to compare sums of price1, price2, price3 etc... of specific id's. 
For example, i have a set of id's 1, 2, 4 and 6. In that case sum of price1 is 11, price2 - 14, price3 - 13, price4 - 11. The question is:
Is there a query to compare and order the results?

Comment: what do you mean by _compare_? What result do you expect and what have you tried already?

Comment: @Lashane I have a list of products with different prices in different shops. Someone picks a set of products and sees the result ordered by sum of prices of those products

Comment: so you wanna sort, not compare?

Comment: @Lashane Well, I am not strong in MySQL, maybe SORT is what i need. Can i use just one query or there's another way?

Answer (score 1):

here is quick sql:

```
select sum(price1), sum(price2), sum(price3), sum(price4)
from table
where id in (1,2,4,6)
```

Comment: Found out there's a mistake. I need to sort (price1 of 1 + price1 of 2 + price1 of 4 + price1 of 6), (price2 of 1 + price2 of 2 + price2 of 4 + price2 of 6), (price3 of 1 + price3 of 2 + price3 of 4 + price3 of 6) etc

Comment: @AlexBetev I've changed code to summarize all prices